# cannot access variable environment from .profile using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, .profile

In my rails application, I exported my database variables in `.profile` using ansible. the variables are accessible by the command `printenv`. However, when I run the application or use `rails c` via `ENV['NAME']` , the variables aren't there.

Does anyone have any idea why rails doesn't load variables from .profile?

Answer (score -1):

The *~/.profile* script is only meant to be read by your (presumably POSIX compatible) shell. And even then only if it is what is known as a "login" shell. For example, from the bash man page:

> When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the --login option,  it first attempts to read and execute commands from /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that order.

If you're running your rails application from an interactive shell prompt it should have access to the env vars you're setting in *~/.profile*. If you're starting your rails app some other way (e.g., from your window manager) then you'll need to find some other way to set the env vars that it inherits.

Comment: I set up my rails application on vagrant running on Ubuntu. It supposed to have access to the env, but it doesnt.